# How to instantiate ToSchema for ADT?

Tags: plutus

If I have

```
data Thing1 = I Integer | S String
```

how do I instantiate [`ToSchema`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/58c8b4bde7177a18cd6761ba328bc105e5c82a47/playground-common/src/Schema.hs#L172) for it?  Note that deriving doesn't work.

And how about for

```
data Thing2 = I Integer | S
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use Sum types with Swagger, see [relevant plutus issue](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues/3861), you need to wait for the following PR adding OpenAPI3 support https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/pull/3807